# Javascript call a c function at the server side

Tags: javascript, c

Is there a way i can call c functions from JavaScript at server side . and if possible back from c to javascript.

Comment: Do you mean from JavaScript code on a web page, or to/from a JavaScript interpreter running at the server?

Comment: use [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and [injection](http://www.patricktalmadge.com/2006/11/28/javascript-injection/)... and google.

Comment: In the server. A javascript can it call a c function call.

Answer (score 2):

It is what we call Ajax.

Ajax allows you to interact with a server using javascript. You don't call directly a C method but you can call the server which in fact can call a C method and then return the response to the client.

Comment: there is no client involved here. just JS do a function call on C.